# Ansible: error when trying to unarchive a .tar.gz retrieved via the "get_url" module

Tags: ansible

I'm using Ansible 1.9.4 on a Debian (Jessie 8.2) virtual machine.

I have a file that is stocked on Google Cloud Platform that I retrieve on the remote via the "get_url" module. But when I try to unzip it with gzip, I get an error saying :

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
```

I can unarchive the file before uploading it or if I retrieve it via the graphic interface on the google developer console.

Do you have an idea of what could cause this ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using gzip, try using `tar` with the *gzip* flag.

```
tar -zxvf myfile.tar.gz
```

**z** - using gzip compression
**x** - extract the archive
**v** - do it verbosely
**f** - use this file

The reason gzip will not work, is because what you actually have is a tarball, that is compressed using gzip, you can not just uncompress it, you need to extract the archive as well.

To *create* a `.tar.gz` file, you again use *tar*.

```
tar -zcvf output.tar.gz dir_to_zip/
```

Again, same flags as before, except this time you will use

**c** - compress

As opposed to `x` which extracts.

Comment: Hi, the error was that I was a dumbass, I messed up pretty badly with ansible variables. This and my crappy internet connection which caused some corruption in the files. But if I recall well tar calls gzip to open tar.gz files. + i got some errors from gzip while when using tar on corrupted files.